# python ggplot scatter emphasize

Tags: python-2.7, scatter-plot, python-ggplot

I do a scatter plot with python 2.7 ggplot. I want the background steelblue but emphasize some points but failed. Can some one help me on that.

Code Piece:

```
from ggplot import *
chart = ggplot( df_color, aes(x='x-tsne', y='y-tsne') )\
                 + geom_point(color='steelblue',size=70,alpha=0.8)\
                 + geom_point(data=df_color.loc[self.GoI,:],aes(x='x-tsne', y='y-tsne'), colour="red",size=5)\
                 + ggtitle("tSNE dimensions")
```

The error follows:

```
line 154
+ geom_point(data=df_color.loc[self.GoI,:],aes(x='x-tsne', y='y-tsne'), colour="red",size=5)\
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule of thumb in Python is that a function call of type `f(a,b,c=something, d,...)` will not work as you call non-keyword (`d`) after a keyword (`c`). Here order is important, while the order of keyword arguments is not, assuming that you give them in the form `keyword=arg`. Python also allows you to give them just as `arg`, which then requires the correct order.

Long story short: read the error message.